# Nuxt2 css (.less) build changes class names in css

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, nuxt.js, css-modules, less-loader

I've got a Nuxt2 app, the problem is that after the build all the class names are changed to unique ids, but only in the css not in html, so obviously it doesn't work. I've read about putting every css   into a `:global {}`, but I really don't want to edit all the `.less` files and all the vue components that includes some `<style>`.

Is there any way to disable this behavior and keep the class names in css?

Here are my related config:

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
  css: [
    '@/assets/less/main.less'
  ],
 build: {
    extend(config, ctx) {
      if (ctx.isDev && ctx.isClient) {
        config.module.rules.push({
          enforce: 'pre',
          test: /\.(js|vue|ts)$/,
          loader: 'eslint-loader',
          exclude: /(node_modules)/
        })
      }
    },
```

`main.less`

```css
@import 'colors';

.main-container {
  position: relative;
}

.some-other-class {
  color: cyan !important;
}

#__nuxt {
  .nuxt-progress {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
...
```

And then at the end of the vue files there are some more css

```html
<style lang="less">
  .foo {
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
  .main-loader {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }

</style>
```

After `nuxt dev` this is what I get:

```html
<style type="text/css">

._2ziUxTIl2ToSZKEtQFWezE {
    color: cyan !important;
}
._2y3yDMBkHmkrDt1g-FaM5L {
    position: relative;
}
...
</style>
```

But in the html the class names are still normal, like `some-other-class` and `main-container`.

If I read about it correctly it has something with css-modules but to be honest I am a bit confused because there are the nuxt, css-loader, less-loader, css-modules, webpack etc, not sure which is the one I am looking for.

Comment: `eslint-loader` is probably not related at all here. The hash (`2ziUxTIl2ToSZKEtQFWezE`) that you have here is usually coming [from this](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#scoped-css) but I don't see any scoping here so it's a bit strange. I don't have any specific experience with LESS but you could probably try to configure it following this guide: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/pre-processors.html#less May be a good start to see from a fresh project, what is not working (easier to debug). Also, `:global` is probably not a good solution here.

Comment: Yeah, i ended up with a new project. I am pretty new to frontend and there are just too many packages frameworks and stuff to handle all at once. Its better to understand all those step by step. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

OP ended up creating a new project because of the difficulty of understanding all the tools in modern frontend.

Answer (score 0):

it seems to be a known issue with nuxt. It happens when declaring styles in non-scoped style tag, and using it somewhere else.